# Countability - Constant Functions

Tags: education, constants

I am learning about countability. I know about diagonalization and I am confused about constant functions and whether or not they are countable.

A constant function in my case would be:

$f(0) = 1,$
$f(1) = 1,$
$f(2) = 1,$
$f(3) = 1,$
$f(1000) = 1.$

So for $f(0) \dots f(9)$ I would have the sequence:

$(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)$

How would I show this is countable or not countable?

I tried diagonalization with:

$1, \, 1, \,1, \,1, \,1, \,1, \,1, \,1, \,1, \,1$  and

$2, \, 2, \,2, \,2, \,2, \,2, \,2, \,2, \,2, \,2$

and created a new sequence:  $2, 3 \dots$ that is not on the original list.

This states that constant functions are not countable, my my intution tells me that they should be countable.

Comment: Are these constant functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed from N to N!

Comment: Did you try showing a bijection between the functions and $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: also note that your new sequence is not a constant function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $\{ f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}  \colon f $ is constant $\}$ is indeed countable, you have the bijection

$n  \longmapsto  f_n$ where $f_n(x) = n$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 0):

Define $f: \{All constant functions N to N\}->N$ by f(g)=g(0).

Note that $f$ is bijective, therefore the set is countable.